# SessionId saved in SQL Server is different from the one generated from the asp.net runtime

Tags: asp.net, sessionid

I have implemented SQL Server session mode for an asp.net application.

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" compressionEnabled="true" 
        sqlConnectionString="Data Source=.;User ID=xxxx;Password=yyyyy;Integrated Security=False;" 
        sqlCommandTimeout="240" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="false" />
```

I created a variable in the `Session_Start` in the `global.asax` file:

```
var sessionID = Session.SessionID;
```

I found the following data while debugging the application:

```
ASP.NET generated : lehxv4so4ioi2gqqaxtjzhyo
SQL Server saved  : lehxv4so4ioi2gqqaxtjzhyo84497b6f
```

Can anyone let me know what is reason for the different results as mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**lehxv4so4ioi2gqqaxtjzhyo***84497b6f*

in bold is your sessionid and in italics is the application id

the extra 8 bytes are the applicationid